# PopupWindow in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I am in need of a popupwindow with the option of a radio button. I have tested with [Impromtu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impromptu_%28programming_environment%29). Is any easy made Popupwindow plugin available?

My plugin should work in Internet Explorer, Mozilla and Google Chrome. What would some sample code be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) is great and easy-to-use for building Modal Popups and the like.

If you want a tutorial on how to build one yourself without jQuery, check out [this tutorial](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)! You can use a div or so on your page as content (see inline content demo).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of lightbox like plugins depending on your need:

http://www.fortysomething.ca/mt/etc/archives/006978.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're not absolutely bent on using jQuery, there is another library available that uses the Prototype library that is rather handy.  The popup windows are very easy to implement, and the modal dialog boxes are even easier.

On a side note, I have used thickbox before and was rather impressed, but the URL parsing structure that it uses were kind of limiting me for what I needed to do (I was using a ComponentArt object that didn't use anchors).

Anyway, definitely check out this tool.  It's probably more than you need, but who knows maybe you'll get inspired to find other uses for it.  It's a pretty fun tool:
 http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

[FaceBox](http://famspam.com/facebox) is another option to check out.