# Modal dialog box which opens new page using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I see lot of example opening popup with jquery but don't see anything that will let me open new page in popup(modal dialog box). Any help is appreciated.

What i am trying to do is when click on item it will open item description page in model dialog box calling an url for detail page. I am using asp.net, would like to use jquery if has nice way to work with popup.

---

#### See also: [PopupWindow in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392698/popupwindow-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; there are actually [many of them](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/modal+type%3Aproject_project). For example: [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/). For a demonstration of how to load a separate page into an [`<iframe>`](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/ThickboxToJqModal/), check out [Alexandre Plennevaux's site](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/ThickboxToJqModal/).

Comment: It's worth noting that <iframe> has been deprecated in XHTML 1.0 Strict. Instead, use <object>.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted HOW one would convert from an iframe to an object tag...

Comment: Fine, just use the "data" attribute instead of iframe's "src". You might also consider specifying the mime type through the "type" attribute.